# Typescript ES6 arrow syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

What is difference between canDeactivate1 & canDeactivate2 in below typescript interface ? How these functions will be considered ?

```
export interface CanComponentDeactivate
{
    canDeactivate1 : ()=> Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
    canDeactivate2 (): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
}
```

How can i write same function in JavaScript ?

Comment: second looks like a function types which should return value of any type after `:`

Comment: It's not a function but an interface which just describes which types are taken or returned

Comment: First one is a property whos type is either: a parameterless method that evaluates into a Observable<boolean>, a boolean promise or a boolean. Second is a parameterless method that returns a value of one of the 3 possible types after `:`

Answer (score 0):

The second is basically a shortcut (well, not much) for the first.

The expression `()=> Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean` is a type declaration for a function that expects no arguments and returns an observable, a promise or a boolean. You can use such declarations anywhere a type is expected:

```
let foo: ()=> Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
foo = 1; //doesn't work, foo has to be a function
foo = () => 1; //doesn't work, we are not allowed to return a number
foo = () => true; // works
foo = function() { return true }; //works
```

Because functions on objects are usually used as methods, interfaces have a special syntax that resembles method declarations in classes. `canDeactivate2 (): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean` looks like a method without a body, which is more in line with what other languages have.